# not changing colors in java GraphicsProgram

Tags: java, random, colors, graphics, awt

The problem is asking me to spawn a circle on the canvas with a click. This part works fine. The next part is if I click a circle it needs to keep switching to random colors from: green, yellow, black, red, blue until the color is green. The code I wrote kinda does change the color but the change doesn't appear visually.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
import acm.util.RandomGenerator;

public class VAR4N5 extends GraphicsProgram {

    private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();

    private final static int CIRCLE_D = 40;
    private final static int DELAY = 50;

    private GOval clickedCircle = null;

    public void run() {
        addMouseListeners();
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (getElementAt(e.getX(), e.getY()) == null) {
            drawCircle(e.getX(), e.getY());
        } else {
            clickedCircle = (GOval) getElementAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
            changeColor();
        }
    }

    private void drawCircle(double xClick, double yClick) {
        double x = xClick - CIRCLE_D / 2.0;
        double y = yClick - CIRCLE_D / 2.0;
        GOval circle = new GOval(CIRCLE_D, CIRCLE_D);
        circle.setFilled(true);
        circle.setFillColor(rgen.nextColor());
        add(circle, x, y);
    }

    private void changeColor() {
        int randomNum = 0;
        while (true) {
            randomNum = rgen.nextInt(1, 5);
            if (randomNum == 1) {
                clickedCircle.setFillColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            }
            if (randomNum == 2) {
                clickedCircle.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            if (randomNum == 3) {
                clickedCircle.setFillColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            if (randomNum == 4) {
                clickedCircle.setFillColor(Color.RED);
            }
            if (randomNum == 5) {
                clickedCircle.setFillColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            clickedCircle.setLocation(clickedCircle.getX(), clickedCircle.getY());
            pause(DELAY);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see either a java.awt.Graphics (or the Graphics2D) reference for painting or a method obtaining one from a circle class that it should have binding to. Neither is there a repaint() method call or a paint() overriden method in the code ! After you command a visual change to anything you must repaint()